# Docstrings for data?

Tags: python, docstring

Is there a way to describe the module's data in a similar way that a docstring describes a module or a funcion?

```
class MyClass(object):
    def my_function():
        """This docstring works!"""
        return True
    my_list = []
    """This docstring does not work!"""
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To my knowledge, it is not possible to assign docstrings to module data members.

[PEP 224](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0224/) suggests this feature, but the PEP was rejected.

I suggest you document the data members of a module in the module's docstring:

```
# module.py:
"""About the module.

module.data: contains the word "spam"

"""

data = "spam"
```

Answer (score 11):

It **is** possible to make documentation of module's data, with use of [epydoc](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/) syntax. Epydoc is one of the most frequently used documentation tools for Python.

The syntax for documenting is `#:` above the variable initialization line, like this:

```
# module.py:

#: Very important data.
#: Use with caution.
#: @type: C{str}
data = "important data"
```

Now when you generate your documentation, `data` will be described as module variable with given description and type `str`. You can omit the `@type` line.

Comment: Even though this is cool, I was looking for exactly docstings (since these are the most helpful in the console environment using help builtin). Anyway thanx

Answer (score 10):

As codeape explains, it's not possible to document general data members.

However, it *is* possible to document `property` data members:

```
class Foo:
  def get_foo(self): ...

  def set_foo(self, val): ...

  def del_foo(self): ...

  foo = property(get_foo, set_foo, del_foo, '''Doc string here''')
```

This will give a docstring to the `foo` attribute, obviously.